# Python, Selenium "::after" problem while scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape automobile information from a dynamic [webpage](https://www.arabam.com/ilan/galeriden-satilik-citroen-c-elysee-1-6-hdi-attraction/fiat-onkol-oto-dan-c-elysee-1-6-attraction-92-hp-beyaz/14046287). However, after running Selenium chrome browser, inspection elements are not shown as they are in original source page. Instead of html code of the car details (Informative area near the product image), " ::after " element is appeared in html source code.

You can see my scraping code below;

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = ("C:\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get('https://www.arabam.com/ilan/galeriden-satilik-citroen-c-elysee-1-6-hdi-attraction/fiat-onkol-oto-dan-c-elysee-1-6-attraction-92-hp-beyaz/14046287')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.table

table_rows = table.find_all('li')
print(table_rows)
```

When i used given code to get relative information from the webpage, i could not see any html attributes which is necessary for further scraping loops.

What can be the reason of that problem and how can i solve that?

Thanks,

Edit;

HTML element content in selenium browser,

[image]

Normal Google Chrome HTML element content that i try to reach,

[image]

Comment: can you give us example of the expected output?

Comment: You can't do that with BS, you need to use getComputedStyle from the browser runtime.

Comment: value = driver.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div.row'),':after').getPropertyValue('content')") ------------------------                                          
I tried that one, and returned null value which is exactly the same content shown in selenium browser. However, i try to reach normal chrome inspection value. This one i think, created after java script codes run. I have to run this java script codes in selenium browser before scraping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no table in the HTML page you provided, try using a different selector. You could try selecting by

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w100 semi-bold lh18")
```

This should give you an ordered list of the `span` elements